# Products not loading on Load More in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, javascript, list-view

The load more button is not working for loading products as shown here.

> https://prnt.sc/p45em5

When i click on load more it shows Loading.

> https://prnt.sc/p45f11

But then again it show load more

> https://prnt.sc/p45em5.

The products are not getting loaded.
May be the script is not called?

Comment: Which infinity scroll extension are you using? is there any javascript errors in the console of your browser? press F12 on your browser to bring the inspector up

Comment: @DavaGordon I am not using any extension. Its a default 'porto' themes functionality.

Comment: id suggest if you purchased the theme then your best contacting there support team